# Run a python script from within python and also catch the exception

Tags: python, file, subprocess

Run a python script from within python and also catch the exception.

```
File: test1.py

try:
    a = 1/0
except:
    raise

File: test2.py

import subprocess
subprocess.call('python test.py', shell=True)
```

How can I run test1.py and also catch the ZeroDivisionError in test2.py ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just import test1?

Comment: test1 is a standalone script which is run as cron job with certain arguments. So I wanted to run the script with system arguments without making script a module.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement):

```
with open('script.py') as f:
    script = f.read()
    try:
        exec(script)
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print('yay!', e)
```

Comment: This works great. But how about you want to execute a perl script within a python.

Comment: @dumper I don't think you can catch a Perl exception from Python. Languages are usually not directly interoperable like this. You should execute non-Python code as a process and check it's return value, e.g. using [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call). This is a conventional way of process result communication, when `0` means successful execution and any other status code returned means an error. Of course the executed process should adhere to the convention and return useful status codes.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you are using subprocess?
I would do it just this way

test1.py

```
def test
    try:
        a = 1/0
    except:
        raise
```

test2.py

```
import test1

try:
    test1.test()
except
    whateveryouwannado
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `try except` and use `function` call will be better,

```
test1.py

def solve():
    try:
        a = 1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print e.message
solve()

test2.py

import subprocess
subprocess.call('python foo.py', shell=True)
```